# How to create diretorys in /var/www on ubuntu? Setting permission

Tags: linux, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

I've just finished Nginx configuration, and now I'm installing python and virtualenv.

I need to create 'test' directory in /var/www for our test case.
But I can't create a directory.

```
$cd /var/www
$mkdir test
```

The output is:

```
 mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied
```

How to fix this error?

How to change the Document Root directory if it's available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs possibly because you have no priviledges as the error suggests.
I presume you're `user` and the folder `/var/www` has UID `root`.

To see the folders access rights you can use the `stat` command -> `stat /var/www`

The output should look like this:

```
File: /var/www
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 1125899907242212  Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2019-08-05 15:38:01.883762500 +0200
Modify: 2019-08-05 15:38:00.815731000 +0200
Change: 2019-08-05 15:38:00.815731000 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Now you can either change the permissions of the folder or create the folder with root priviledges.

### Root priviledges

`sudo mkdir /var/www/test` or when inside `/var/www` use `sudo mkdir test`

### Changing permissions

To change permissions of a folder you use the command `chown` (See [help](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) for more info)
The command requires root priviledges as well.

Syntax
`sudo chown UID:GID folder`

Example
`sudo chown hackxit:users folder`

Since your folder might have other folders inside, you can add the `-r` option to change the permissions recursively.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a directory by using sudo as the owner for the var/www folder is root.